# C# Dynamic Type Initialization From JSON

Tags: c#, json, parsing, dynamic, reflection

I am trying to dynamically instantiate a class from my visual studio solution based on a JSON string.

Before I describe my exact issue I want to give an example of what I want to achieve.
Say I have the following JSON :

```
{
    "Type": "AutoIncrementTag,
    "StartFrom": 0,
    "Skip": 10,
    "LeadingZero": false
}
```

So from that Json, I want to find the class called "AutoIncrementTag" and instantiate it, setting its "*StartFrom*", "*Skip*" and "*LeadingZero*" parameters to the correspoding values.

**Note 1:** I have a couple of theese "Tag" classes and I want to instantiate a different on the "Type" attribute in my Json string.

**Note 2:** My Json string will contain more than 1 of these class "descriptions" (I believe they are called JSON Objects but I'm not too familliar with the JSON format just yet)

**Note 3**: I am using Newtonsoft.Json for all the Json parsing/converting.

So, now for my issue.

I managed to get the Type property using

```
JObject.Parse(myJsonString).GetValue("Type").ToString();
```

However, **how would I go about getting all the other values**, since they will be different depending on what Type I have? (I need a way to dynamically iterate and get the values of the other properties.)

And second, how do I then map these properties to a C# object.
I thought about using

```
Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, object[] args)
```

But **how can I (dynamically) get an object[] from the properties described in my json format**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.Net (i.e. Newtonsoft.Json) does this for you already. For example, lets start off with a basic class:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string AnotherValue { get; set; }
}
```

And an instance of it:

```
var thing = new Thing { SomeValue = 5, AnotherValue = "blah" };
```

We can deserialise with a custom settings object, specifically setting the [`TypeNameHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) property

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thing, settings);
```

Which will give output something like this:

```
{
    "$type":"Thing, Namespace",
    "SomeValue": 5,
    "AnotherValue": "blah"
}
```

And to get it back into the right kind of object, just use the same settings:

```
var anotherThing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
```

Comment: Hmm, can't believe its that simple :D.
However, the following method returns an object.
How do I go about getting the exact type i.e "Thing"  as a result, instead ob object.

Do i read the "type" property of the json and then cast the resulting object to it, or is there a built-in way for that as well? :D

Comment: Whatever method you use, you will always get an `object`. In this case, it would be your class assigned to a variable of type `object`